# When to use a web framework and when to code with native language for android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

It's been a time that I developp on android using the native language on Eclipse ADT and Android Studio.

Mastering most of the "standard" stuff (services, broadcaster, accelerometer, online/offline apps, local and remote databases, ntf scanning, socket.io libraries etc...), I wanted to find new ways to architect my apps, and I ve finally found new ways to code, using Web Frameworks to make compiled applications.

Suddenly I was wondering, when to use which technolgy, for example :

- ionic framework (with angular included & cordova)
- phonegap & cordova
- native language
- other frameworks or ways to code

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

All about technology depend on your application, depend on time and your app complexity. If you are going with Cross platform apps, unquestionably cross platform is going to be more robust in the time to come. There is a simple rule for Cross platform apps, “write once use several times”. Same code can be used on multiple platforms but this requires a lot of customization to be able to match each platform’s individual requirements. HTML5 seems to be ruling the market due to its dynamic usage for building apps with different run times, patterns and frameworks. The PhoneGap framework whose name was changed lately by “Apache Cordova” is the best amongst all other tools. In this framework the developers write the mobile app in HTML, CSS and JavaScript....[More about PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview)